# Why is my loop terminating before all items are looped through?

Tags: python, html, django, github

So I'm using Django and trying to dynamically add a users gists to the page using githubs embedded gists.

this is the loop

```
{% for i in snippets %}
    <div class="tile is-4">
        <div style="height:25vh;"><script src="https://gist.github.com/{{i.owner.login}}/{{i.id}}.js"/></div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

the list im looping through contains two items, however only the first is added.
if I do something along these lines however it correctly displays the two different id's

```
{% for i in snippets %}
   {{i.id}}
{% endfor %}
```

I read that the github script calls `document.write()`, I have a gut feeling this is where my issue lies.

Would `document.write()` break my loop?

Comment: Are you user `i` has an `owner` field?  Without the write flags set, Django can sometimes do strange things when it encounters an error.  I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: just checked and it'll work when outputting the owner field like the second example. Such a strange problem.

Comment: What happens when you instead use `{{i.id}}/{{i.id}}'.  I know that's not what you want, but I'm curious if you get one line or two.  Like I said, everything looks normal to me.